# Find Azure Subscription based on Application Insights's Instrumentation Key

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a way to find out given instrumentation key belongs to which subscription?

Answer (score 0):

First go to Azure Cloud Shell. It gives you bash and allows you to access all your azure resources.

Second create a file findApplicationByIkey.sh with the following content:

```
!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$ikeyToFind" ]; then
    echo "specify the instrumentaiton key"
    exit
fi
echo "search for instrumentation key $1"
ikeyToFind=$1

# this function search for the instrumentation key in a given subscription
function findIKeyInSubscription {
  echo "Switch to subscription $1"
  az account set --subscription $1

  # list all the Application Insights resources.
  # for each of them take an instrumentation key 
  # and compare with one you looking for
  az resource list \
    --namespace microsoft.insights --resource-type components --query [*].[id] --out tsv \
      | while \
          read ID; \
          do  printf "$ID " && \
              az resource show --id "$ID" --query properties.InstrumentationKey --o tsv; \
        done \
      | grep "$ikeyToFind"
}

# run the search in every subscription...
az account list --query [*].[id] --out tsv \
    | while read OUT; do findIKeyInSubscription $OUT; done
```

Finally, run it: ./findApplicationByIkey.sh provide key here

e.g. `./findApplicationByIkey.sh e645a06e-d500-402e-ad4a-0bdcc4062dab`

```
Test@Azure:~/Test$ ./findApplicationByIkey.sh e645a06e-d500-402e-ad4a-0bdcc4062dab
search for instrumentation key e645a06e-d500-402e-ad4a-0bdcc4062dab
A few accounts are skipped as they don't have 'Enabled' state. Use '--all' to display them.
Switch to subscription 
Switch to subscription 
...
...
```

Final output will be like -

```
/subscriptions/<subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/MY-RG/providers/microsoft.insights/components/test-ai-app
```

Comment: Will this solution find azure subscription in my account? What if the Instrument key belongs to someone's personal subscription? Will it find too?

Comment: No and that may not be appropriate as well from security stand point.

Comment: Wouldn't it a security issue if someone injects his/her instrument key? That's what happens to our code and we are trying to see whose key it this?

Comment: Honestly, prevent your key from being injectable by foreign agents, for Christ's sake... How can you not have control and visibility of your application configuration? You're trying to solve the wrong problem, I believe.